# Creating one file from another based on search terms

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How can I create a file that contains everything after and including a particular search term from another file in the terminal?

Example:

**Original file content**: foo, bar, baz, qux

**Search term**: baz

**New file content**: baz, qux

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU grep, and the same example as in your question, the following would do:

```
$ echo 'foo, bar, baz, qux' | grep -o '\bbaz\b.*'
baz, qux
```

Option `-o` asks grep to print only the part of the line that matches,
and `\b` ensures that `baz` is matched at word boundaries.

Comment: This goes part of the way to solving this, but wasn't usable for entries with multiple lines, and I also need to take one file as the input and another as the output.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used [pcregrep](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pcregrep1.html) for this. The best usage I found for returning everything after the search term in a multiline file is the below, substituting for searchTerm, originalFile and newFile:

```
pcregrep -M 'searchTerm((.|\n)*)' originalFile > newfile
```